# Using Fragment fullscreen on AppCompatActivity with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a main AppCompatActivity with a navigation drawer. The main AppCompatActivity is not fullscreen, so you can still see the status bar on the top of the screen. However, I do want a fragment to occupy the entire screen when the fragment is shown to the user. Is that possible, if so how? Please provide any links for any examples if available. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I understood that you want to load a `Fragment` in `AppCompatActivity`. Before loading that fragment activity shouldn't be full-screen. After loading that fragment, activity should be full-screen. am I correct ??

Comment: When the application first launches, the main activity executes. During the onCreate() of the activity, I use fragment manager to add the fragment object that I want to be in fullscreen mode. When the user taps on that fragment, it hides/closes and it goes back to the main activity that is not fullscreen.

Comment: min api of your app ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this kind of implementation in you `Activity` :

```
SystemUiHider mUiHider = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //go full screen with no title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS); //show progress on loadup
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, mainLayout, SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    mUiHider.setup();
    mUiHider.setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
            if (visible) {
                mUiHider.hide(); 
                final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
                final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mUiHider.hide();
                    }
                };
                mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
                mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, 1000); 
            }
        }
    });
    mUiHider.hide();
}
```